# How can I get the role of the author of the message using Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to create a bot for my discord server and I need to get the role of the author when someone sends a message in order to execute some functions.

I've looked at the documentation and a lot of answers on other posts but I can't find.

How can I get the role of the author of the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var author = guild.members.resolve(message.author.id);
var isSiteAdmin = author.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'site-admin');
```